# Can the below class thread safety ever be broken; I am sure it can't be but just wanted to be doubly sure as it is not easy to test

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashset

```
public class ThreadSafe implements ITaskCompletionListener {

private final Set<String> taskIds = new HashSet<String>();
private final Set<String> successfulIds = new HashSet<String>();
private final Set<String> cancelledIds = new HashSet<String>();
private final Set<String> errorIds = new HashSet<String>();

public ThreadSafe() {

}

// invoked concurrently
@Override
public void onCancel(String pTaskId) {
    remove(pTaskId);
    cancelledIds.add(pTaskId);
}

// invoked concurrently
@Override
public void onError(String pTaskId) {
    remove(pTaskId);
    errorIds.add(pTaskId);
}

// invoked concurrently
@Override
public void onSuccess(String pTaskId) {
    remove(pTaskId);
    successfulIds.add(pTaskId);
}

private void remove(String pTaskId) {
    taskIds.remove(pTaskId);
}

}
```

Comment: I tried to break down the problem into a simplistic question which didn't go as per plan. Thanks for your answers. Shrugging off the laziness I updated the problem and the solution I used as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is riddled with thread-safety problems.

HashSet is not thread-safe (it is based on the non-threads-safe HashMap - race conditions in which can end up causing [infinite loops](http://mailinator.blogspot.com/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html)).

Secondly, there is no atomicity between an ID being in the `taskIds` set and it being added to one of the others, so a task's existence is ephemeral.

Thirdly, the code implicitly assumes that the task state is simply inProgress -> success|error|cancel and that there is no concurrent task execution. If this is not true then the code fails.

Answer (score 8):

From the [`HashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) docs:

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access a hash set concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the set, it *must* be synchronized externally

So no, your code is not thread-safe. Concurrent accesses to any of your methods could have strange results.

Comment: it is worse than that due to the non-atomic nature of the set operations

Answer (score 4):

Rather than having lots of sets and passing ids between collections, you can use a single collection which is thread safe.

```
private final ConcurrentMap<String, State> idState = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, State>();
enum State { TASK, SUCCESS, CANCELLED, ERROR }

public void onSuccess(String taskId) {
    idState.put(taskId, State.SUCCESS);
}

public void onCancelled(String taskId) {
    idState.put(taskId, State.CANCELLED);
}

public void onError(String taskId) {
    idState.put(taskId, State.ERROR);
}

public void remove(String taskId) {
    idState.remove(taskId);
}
```

Comment: Peter, you are assuming like the OP that task execution is isolated (no more than one execution per taskId). Using the conditional update (replace) methods on concurrent map would make this safer if this is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 1):

Methods `onError`, `onSuccess`, and `onCancel` can be invoked in parallel by two or more threads, which could eventually invoke `taskIds.remove` in parallel, which is NOT thread-safe.

Just mark these three methods as `synchronized` and you should be done.

Comment: Or -- change every field initializer like this: private final Set<String> taskIds = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>());

Comment: actually making the individual collections synchronized will make the code technically thread-safe but probably not conceptually thread-safe in that the movement between sets is probably expected to be conceptually atomic.

Comment: Good point! So go with the synchronized on the public methods :)

Answer (score 1):

Peter is right.
"Rather than having lots of sets and passing ids between collections, you can use a single collection which is thread safe."

This would make it a bit less complex and make it look uneasy to break.

Comment: Hi @Jennah, welcome to SO! I just wanted to mention to you that generally speaking it is considered poor etiquette to add a personal signature to your posts. SO will automatically add a signature for you and people will look at your profile with the provided link. Here is the FAQ (the portion on signatures is near the bottom): http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use synchronization block in methods which are called concurrently .

example

```
public void onCancel(String pTaskId) {
synchronized(this){
    remove(pTaskId);
    cancelledIds.add(pTaskId);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to each one of you for responding and also for pointing out the obvious bloopers in the code I pasted. I will give a context of the problem I am solving.

I will receive requests (each request will have a set of task id's); I have a thread pool which would be used to submit this request (batch of tasks for each request). I will accept from the clients listeners that would be invoked after task completion. In the current context, I could have used an `ExecutorCompletionService` to wait for all the tasks corresponding to a request to complete, however, I do not wish to make any blocking calls.

Instead I wish to subclass `FutureTask` (override `done()` method) and this would be instantiated in `newTaskFor()` of my subclasses executor service. All the future tasks corresponding to one request will share the `TaskCompletionListener`, and in the override `done()` method will invoke one of `success()`, `error()` or cancel. The `TaskCompletionListener`, will be initialized with the initial set of task id (number of tasks) and for each invocation will decrement the count by one after which the completion would be signaled.

Here is a modified version of the code, I hope I haven't committed much mistakes this time around (and yes, thanks once again for all the answers last time around).

```
public class TaskCompletionListener implements ITaskCompletionListener {

private final AtomicInteger taskCount;

private final IProcessCompletionListener completionListener;

public TaskCompletionListener(final HashSet<String> pTaskIds, IProcessCompletionListener pCompletionListener) {
    taskCount = new AtomicInteger(pTaskIds.size());
    completionListener = pCompletionListener;
}

// invoked concurrently
@Override
public void onCancel(String pTaskId) {
    checkCompletion();
}

// invoked concurrently
@Override
public void onError(String pTaskId) {
    checkCompletion();
}

// invoked concurrently
@Override
public void onSuccess(String pTaskId) {
    checkCompletion();
}

private void checkCompletion() {
              // method level confinement  
    int currentCount = taskCount.decrementAndGet();
    if (currentCount == 0) {
        completionListener.onProcessComplete();
    }
}

interface IProcessCompletionListener {
    void onProcessComplete();
}
}
```